# Sproutcore vs Cappuccino speed

Tags: javascript, cappuccino, sproutcore

I am evaluating sproutcore and cappuccino for use in my current project. Since I am a rails developer and I like pure javascript I think that sproutcore suits my style better. My problem is that every single sproutcore sample I have tested seems very slugish and slow on its user interface. Scrolling is very slow, clicking on buttons has a delay e.t.c. On the other hand all the cappuccino samples seem very responsive despite that fact that they are more full blown applications than the sproutcore samples.

I dont have a problem diving into objective-j although it currently makes my eyes sore. Do you guys think it is worth the trouble or are the speed issues just my idea. I really dont want to commit to something that I will not be able to optimize later.

Comment: Which SproutCore samples have you tested? Are you running `sc-server` to test them, or are you trying build versions? I haven't seen the sluggish behavior you mention, and might be able to suggest other examples with better performance.

Comment: I have tested the samples online at http://demo.sproutcore.com/ and at http://www.sproutcore.com/static/photos/. In the first link the Greenhouse app never loads. In the controls sample in the collections tab scrolling the lists is very sluggish. I have verified this in my own sample also that talked to a server and loaded thousands of items (I have loaded millions with jquery slick grid and scrolling instantly fast). In the photos demo resizing the images is pretty slow. Moving the mouse on the slider and slider tick does not follow the mouse instantly.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look like there's a demo online to test, but [this product](http://www.eloqua.com/eloqua10/take-the-tour.html) is SproutCore powered. For a hands-on demo, try [this tasks demo](http://tasks-demo.appspot.com/) (login "SG", no password).

I'd also recommend taking an afternoon to walk through the demo apps on the wiki. That will give you an idea not only of the speed but of the rate at which you'll ramp up.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I have already studied extensively all the sproutcore samples as well as the cappuccino ones. I have even created my own sample apps with both frameworks. Most of my tests were done with firefox 4 bet on the mac and I realized that its performance sucks for some reason. Safari had much greater performance on both frameworks. My big problem with sproutcore is that scrolling is pretty choppy even in safari for most applications so I think I am going to go with cappuccino even though I like the pure javascript approach of sc a bit better. Both frameworks are pretty nice.

Comment: Sounds like you did a thorough investigation and made an informed decision. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Apple's MobileMe's web-interface is also SproutCore-powered.